# Facebook PHP SDK superbly slow

Tags: php, facebook, performance, curl

Do you guys know why my server took like 15secs to retrieve data from Facebook Graph?

I tried to ping facebook server using my server, and it's kinda stable 90-93ms.

Is it because of my server, or does it has something to do with PHP/cURL version?

This is the example of latest FB PHP-SDK Example.php, I only change the Timeout and insert the load time code :

http://www.foniara.com/facebook-php-sdk-5a88ed7/examples/example.php

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook can definitely be slow when making API calls. It can be a good practice to store data locally after it has been retrieved and cache it for a while depending on what data you're looking to retrieve. You can find out what the culprit is with Firebug by using the net tab. Chrome and IE have similar features, just press F12 to pull up their developer tools.

Are you running on a shared hosting platform or dedicated server? I have about a dozen servers and FaceBook works faster when I run the app on a dedicated server rather than one of my public ones.

Comment: Have you tried the Firebug net tab to see where the biggest load times are?

Comment: I ran your example.php from here and i'm seeing just slightly quicker load times (couple of seconds). The first thing I would check is to make sure your firewall is not causing any conflicts. Additionally, You can try and comment the facebook calls out, see what the load time is, uncomment them top down one by one and check load times again. This will give you an idea where in the script all of the time is being spent. Also, try to run that example on localhost (u could use xampp) and see if you experience the same load times.

Comment: Also I wrote a tutorial using the latest PHP SDK and some of the javascript SDK, try and set that up so we can test my methods in that script on your server. It should also give you a good starting point http://www.epixseo.com/index.php/facebook-php-3-3-1-and-javascript-sdk-graph-api-tutorial/

Comment: Hmm, I think I've found the problem. I tried to login using VNC and surf some sites with it, and it really dam slow. It took 10> secs to load google and fb. I think I'll find another host. Thanks alot btw :)